# How to login as root from Bash and do stuff

Tags: linux, bash, login, sudo, su

This is my simple bash:

```
cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
su - root -c /path/to/script.sh <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

But I get this error:

```
./test.sh
hello
su: must be run from a terminal
<current-user>
good bye
```

(OR)

```
cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
sudo su <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

Again another error

(OR)

```
cat test3.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
su root <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

again error...

when I try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
sudo -s <<EOF
<password>
echo Now I am root
id                                                                      
echo "yes!"
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

Then the output is:

```
./script.sh
hello
[sudo] password for <user>:
```

I also changed my script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sudo -s <<EOF
expect "assword for user:"
send -- "password\r"
expect eof
```

and output is:

```
spawn sudo -s <<EOF
[sudo] password for user:
/bin/bash: <<EOF: command not found
```

Also `which sh` output is `/bin/sh`

How can I resolve the error in these three scripts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this... here are some:

1. login as that user: for real,

   su user2

or just get the same environment,

```
  su -l user2
```

2. execute a single command as that user:

   su user2 -c cat myfile.txt
3. use here docs:

   `sudo su user <<EOF`

   `command1`

   `command2`

   `.....`

   `EOF`

Your commands may fail because /tmp/script.sh is not executable, or because the last echo in one.sh does not have the matching apex (<kbd>"</kbd>).

Comment: I didn't got `su user <` new syntax?

Comment: see my update...the error occurs

Comment: don't work..I'm afraid

Comment: @MortezaLSC And yet it's funny, because it does work on my systems Debian, Kubuntu, Arch Linux. You must have copied something wrong.

Comment: you mean I use your heredoc solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sudo` and grant your (original) user the permission to run /tmp/script.sh as the desired user without password:

```
original_user ALL=(script_user) NOPASSWD: /tmp/script.sh
```

Invoke like so:

```
sudo -u script_user /tmp/script.sh
```

Still, it's a terrible idea to do so with anything relating to a world-writable directory. You're just asking for it by doing that.

Comment: **Don't use this.** Not voting down because they mentioned it's a "terrible idea".

Comment: I don't see what's generally wrong with that. Apart from the script's location.

Comment: Hence why I didn't vote you down, in and of itself, you are right, isn't fully evil.

Answer (score 2):

**I GOT ANSWER FROM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862973/how-to-login-as-root-from-bash-and-do-stuff/21863534#21863534)**

Doing this kind of stuff is not safe or standard practice (in fact many consider it disasterous), it is really not a good idea to put a password in a script. A more standard approach would be simply to expect the whole script to be executed with root privileges, or just to have the script prompt for a password. You can also allow various commands to be run via sudo without a password by particular users by using the `NOPASSWD` option in `/etc/suoders`.

However, now that you are aware of the risks, it is possible to use `sudo -kS` to have sudo read the password from `stdin` and have bash read commands from `stdin` with `-`. Eg:

```
sudo -kS bash - << EOF
password
whoami
echo "Not a good idea to have a password encoded in plain text"
EOF
```